# How can I edit/delete the wrong word in the spell check dictionary in macOS Sonoma 14.0?

Tags: macos, spell-check, dictionary, whatsapp, macos-sonoma

I accidentally added an incorrect word to the spell check dictionary when I use the WhatsApp Desktop.app on macOS Sonoma. How can I edit/delete the wrong word?

I browsed System Settings / Keyboard and I can only find the text replacement section, but not the spell check section.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they've moved in Sonoma [which I can't check yet] they live in `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`.
There may be three. I have Local, then en & en_gb

They should be openable & editable in TextEdit.

You may need to relaunch running apps, or even log out & back to make it see the new spelling.